# Mocha uncaught assertion error status response ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000

Tags: express, mocha.js, chai

Getting an error, when checking to see if index page renders hello world.

> index page should render, hello world
>          should render hello world 200:
>        Uncaught AssertionError: expected [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000] to have keys 'status', or 'statusCode'

**router.spec.test**

```
import chai from 'chai';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';
import { assert } from 'chai'
import router from '../routes/';

chai.use(chaiHttp);


// simple test
describe('Array', () => {
      it('should return -1 when the value is not present', () => {
        assert.equal([1, 2, 3].indexOf(4), -1);
      });
});



describe('index page should render, hello world', () => {
it('should render hello world 200', (done) => {     
    chai.request('http://localhost:5000/')
        .get('/').end((res)=>{

            expect(res).to.have.status(200);
            done();
        });
    })    
})
```

**routes/index.js**

```
import express from 'express';

const app = express();


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.status(200).json({
        message: "Hello World"
    })
})




export default app;
```

Answer (score 0):

ECONNREFUSED is pretty clear, your server isn't running. That's because you've supplied the url as a string, not the express instance. You need to either fire it up manually (not ideal), or provide the router to the chai requester.

So

```
chai.request(router)
  .get('/') .....
```

should work for you.